How do I avoid a socket timeout with Spring AI ImagePrompt?
I have the following in my controller...
    @GetMapping("/openai/image")
    public String generate(@RequestParam(value = "message") String message) {
        ImageOptions options = ImageOptionsBuilder.builder()
                .withModel("dall-e-3")
                .withHeight(1024)
                .withWidth(1024)
                .build();

        ImagePrompt imagePrompt = new ImagePrompt(message, options);
        ImageResponse response = imageModel.call(imagePrompt);
        String imageUrl = response.getResult().getOutput().getUrl();

        return "redirect:" + imageUrl;
    }

But when it runs I get
2024-11-06T22:16:29.589-05:00 ERROR 23191 --- [my-spring-ai] [nio-8055-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServ
let] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations": timeout] with root cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:675) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.kt:684) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:143) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:97) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:na]

What is the proper way to configure this to work? Maybe increase the timeout on the okhttp client?
Also is there a MessageChatMemoryAdvisor messageChatMemoryAdvisor equivalent for image search?

I got it by adding
    @Bean
    RestClientCustomizer restClientCustomizer() {
        return restClientBuilder -> {
            restClientBuilder
                    .requestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(
                            ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings.DEFAULTS
                                    .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                                    .withReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
                            )));
        };
    }

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ai/issues/1634
